# How to remove decimal values display from form field that is automatically coming from backend

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, input

In my form field i want to enter only integer values. i am using ruby moneyrails gem. my field name in db is amount_paisas. so when it is displayng in form it shows `0.00` . i need only `0` to dispaly there. how to avoid decimal values . i tried to give placeholder but no changes.

This is what iam getting in form display.here i need to avoid values after point

[image]

This value is automatically coming from backend. how to remove this?

my input field

`= f.input :amount, label: 'Amount'+'('+@cart.currency+')', :input_html=>{:'data-validation' => 'required', :'data-validation-error-msg' => 'Please Select Amount'}`

here iam not giving any value. but it is automatically getting `0.00` as its placeholder value from  backend. this i need to avoid.

when i inspectin this form field  i am getting like this

`<input data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please Select Amount" class="string optional form-control valid" type="text" value="0.00" name="e_gift_card[amount]" id="e_gift_card_amount">`
Any help is appreciatable ..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

### [Configure default formatting](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#configuration-parameters)

Create `config/initializers/money.rb` file with the following content:

```
MoneyRails.configure do |config|

  config.default_format = {
    :no_cents_if_whole => true,
  #  :symbol => nil,
  #  :sign_before_symbol => nil
  }

end
```

This configuration won't output cents if you have whole amount, i.e. `$5` instead of `$5.00`.

### [Use custom helpers](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#helpers)

If you don't want your cents at all, just use custom helpers:

```
money_without_cents(@money_object) # => 6
money_without_cents_and_with_symbol(@money_object) # => $6
```

To use it in your ruby code:

```
= f.input :amount, label: 'Amount'+'('+@cart.currency+')', :input_html=>{ :value => money_without_cents(@cart.amount), :'data-validation' => 'required', :'data-validation-error-msg' => 'Please Select Amount'}
```

Comment: This is my form input field,appearing like a placeholder value. if i use money_without_cents(@money_object) then i will get dispay value that it fetches from database. but i require here is form input value to change

Comment: If you just want it to fill with default value without using any existing `@money_object`, such as `0`, well, just use `0` without any dots: `<input data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="Please Select Amount" class="string optional form-control valid" type="text" value="0" name="e_gift_card[amount]" id="e_gift_card_amount">`

Comment: my form field is in ruby.like this . here iam not using any value field. `= f.input :amount, label: 'Amount'+'('+@cart.currency+')', :input_html=>{:'data-validation' => 'required', :'data-validation-error-msg' => 'Please Select Amount'}`

Comment: Try moving my `value: money_without_cents(@cart.amount)` to `input_html { }` block

Comment: please edit your answer above. so that i can accept it